# Why would properly VLAN tagged multicast traffic not arrive on the tagged interface?

Tags: networking, rhel, vlan, multicast

I'm working with an application that sends multicast traffic between a client and server. This traffic is sent via multicast. The client and server are both using VLAN interfaces, and need to communicate on a specific VLAN in order to properly talk to one another. The client and server are on the same subnet (so there are no network hops) and their IP's are in the same subnet (so the only routing going on is a route for the multicast to go out the proper VLAN interface).

Using `tcpdump` I can see the traffic on the untagged interface from both hosts, but if I look at the tagged interface, I only see the local machine's traffic. I confirmed that the traffic coming in the untagged interface has the proper vlan tag as well.

To help illustrate this, let's say:

```
VLAN: 10
Multicast: 239.1.1.1
```

What I'm seeing is:

```
[root@client]# tcpdump -ei ens192 host 239.1.1.1
.... vlan 10 ... client.[port] > 239.1.1.1.[port]
.... vlan 10 ... server.[port] > 239.1.1.1.[port]
.... vlan 10 ... client.[port] > 239.1.1.1.[port]
.... vlan 10 ... server.[port] > 239.1.1.1.[port]
```

and the same idea from the other side:

```
[root@server]# tcpdump -ei ens192 host 239.1.1.1
.... vlan 10 ... server.[port] > 239.1.1.1.[port]
.... vlan 10 ... client.[port] > 239.1.1.1.[port]
.... vlan 10 ... server.[port] > 239.1.1.1.[port]
.... vlan 10 ... client.[port] > 239.1.1.1.[port]
```

But when I `tcpdump` the tagged interface:

```
[root@client]# tcpdump -ei ens192.10 host 239.1.1.1
.... client.[port] > 239.1.1.1.[port]
.... client.[port] > 239.1.1.1.[port]
```

Same idea from the server.

I've tried `sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0` with no change.

I also ran `strace -fe trace=network -p [PID of software] 2>&1 | grep 239.1.1.1` on both client and server, and there were only `send_to` calls being made, nothing received (which I expected after not seeing incoming on the tagged interface).

I also confirmed with `ip maddr` that `ens192.10` is subscribed to `239.1.1.1`, though all of the other VLAN interfaces are also subscribed which I found a bit suspicious. I confirmed with `tcpdump` that the traffic isn't coming in on any of the other VLAN interfaces. I'll admit I don't know how this software is performing the subscriptions since I have no access to the internals/source code.

Operating system is RHEL 7.5.

Is there any reason why properly tagged VLAN traffic wouldn't appear on the appropriate VLAN interface?

EDIT: Also, there is other mutlicast traffic working just fine on this VLAN interface, the problem seems specific to this software.

Comment: Stupid question, just in case: The vlan interface has the correct tag, address etc. (`ip -d addr show dev ens192.10`)?

Comment: What sits between the client and server? One switch or more than one switch?

Comment: @dirkt Yes, the vlan is tagged correctly and there's lots of other traffic flowing properly on the vlan. BTW, interfaces named `[int].XX` *have* to be tagged with the `XX` as the vlan: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-kickstart-syntax#idm140244748034544 (scroll down to the `interfacename=` option.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick A Cisco nexus switch. Only a single switch* (technically 2 nexus switches using virtual port channels, but that essentially acts as a single switch). Though I will say that there is other multicast working fine on this VLAN.

Comment: How does the working-fine multicast traffic and its endpoints differ from the non-working multicast traffic?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick different software creating it, so the address/port is different. But otherwise the headers are identical aside from the packet length. VLAN, ethertype, TTL, flags, etc. are all identical. (used `tcpdump -vei ens192 host [maddr]` on a working/broken address and compared.)

Comment: Maybe they *have* to be tagged consistently in whatever Red Hat uses, but it's easy to create inconsistently tagged ones: E.g. `ip link add link eth0 name eth0.6 type vlan id 20` (I just tried). And typos happen...

Comment: @dirkt Fair enough that it can, though we only configure systems through kickstart files since we re-image them quite frequently (bi-weekly). I also confirmed the ID in this case is set accurately.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can user `tcpdump` on a subinterface (i.e. `ens192.10`) like this on Linux.

The usual way to dump a specific (or all) vlan traffic is

```
tcpdump -i ens192 -e vlan 10 and host 239.1.1.1 # just vlan tag 10
tcpdump -i ens192 -e vlan and host 239.1.1.1 # all tagged vlans
```

or, if your `tcpdump` version does not support the `vlan X` syntax, you can match raw headers with

```
tcpdump -i ens192 -e 'ether[12:2] = 0x8100 and ether[15] = 10' and host 239.1.1.1
```

Comment: you definitely can use `tcpdump` on a virtual (sub) interface like this. I can `tcpdump` without a filter and see lots of working traffic and use it regularly.

Comment: @Centimane it might depend on the `tcpdump` version, then. On my servers (admittedy, they have a quite old Ubuntu version) it misses lots of traffic while using the `vlan X` syntax shows a lot more going on.